Doubt about an inverse-system related to the $P\pm P = 2\Bbb{Z}$ problem. What obvious limits must occur?
I'm trying to prove that $P \pm P = 2\Bbb{Z}$ (either case $+$ or $-$) where $P = \{ \pm 1, q : q \text{ is an odd prime}\}$.
I have a doubt though.
Let $f_{n+1,n} : \Bbb{Z}/p_{n+1}\# \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/p_n\#$ be the natural ring surjections (an inverse-system) and let $U_n = \Bbb{Z}/p_n\#^{\times}$ be the group of units modulo the primorial.  If $L = \varprojlim \Bbb{Z}/p_n\#$ then $U = L^{\times} = \varprojlim U_n$.  But what if we union in:
$$
X_1 = U_1 \\
X_2 = a_2 \sqcup U_2 \\
X_3 = \{a_2, a_3\} \sqcup U_3 \\
\vdots
$$
Then is it automatically true that whenever $X_n$ is an inverse-system itself that:
$$
\varprojlim X_n = U \sqcup \{a_2,a_3, \dots\}
$$
?
In other words, does the obvious thing happen here?

Note: all limits are taken as the inverse-limit of the appropriate restriction maps of the original $f$'s.


This is an inverse system because for instance $f_{i,2}(p_i) \in U_2$ for $i \gt 2$ and $f_{i,2}(p_2) = p_2 \in \{p_2\}$.  Note also, by definition of the $f_{i,j}$ maps being simply modulo, they are compatible with the projection maps.
Now let's suppose that $\pi_i: X \to U_i \sqcup \{p_2, \dots, p_i\}$, that are also compatible with the $f$'s.  Then we want to show that there exists a unique map $u:X \to U \sqcup \Bbb{P}_{\geq 3}$ such that $u(x) \mod p_i\# = \pi_i(x)$.
This map is given by $u(x) = (\pi_i(x))_{i \geq 1}$.    If $v(x)$ were another such mapping, then $v(x) = u(x) \mod p_i\#$ which means $v = u$ as a map into an inverse system. $\blacksquare$
Question. Is this an acceptable proof of the this particular limit?

Note that I'm not looking for commutation with $\sqcup$ as individually the ${a_2, \dots, a_n}$ may not form an inverse-system on their own.  Some of them map via $f$ into the next unit group.

Any ideas on this? My first guess is use the UMP.
